# Get rid of "add shortcut to OneDrive" ad

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-teams

Whenever I work with files in Teams, a blue marker is blinking below "Add shortcut to OneDrive".

It started a few weeks ago, at first I thought it's just highlighting a new feature, however now it's really disturbing.

Is there a way to get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: If nobody on your Teams needs that link, then contact your tenant admin, and have them [read this article](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2021/05/how-to-remove-add-shortcut-to-onedrive-in-sharepoint-online.html).  While the article is specifically for Sharepoint, there should be a Teams equivalent cmdlet.